# How to bind function to an object by reference?

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have the following code to bind a member function to an instance of the class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int i;
    void test() {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.i = 100;
    auto func = std::bind(&Foo::test, std::forward<Foo>(f));
    f.i = 1000;
    func();
}
```

But the `std::bind` statement does not bind to `f` by reference. Calling `func` prints "100" instead of "1000" which is what I want.

However, If I change the statement to take a pointer it works.

```
auto func = std::bind(&Foo::test, &f);
```

But this is passing `f` by pointer by my understanding, and as I thought `std::bind` takes an r-value reference `Arg&&` (as shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) how can this work?

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Can you use lambdas? `auto func = [&](){f.test();};    func();`. That should capture the value of `f` by reference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Note on using `std::forward`

First of all, `std::forward` is meant to be used for [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/873025), i.e. to forward the reference type (l-value or r-value).

If you pass an *l-value* reference to `std::forward` that is what is returned, and likewise if an *r-value* reference is passed then an r-value is returned. This works as opposed to `std::move` that will always return an r-value reference. Also remember that *named* r-value references are l-value references.

```
/* Function that takes r-value reference. */
void func(my_type&& t) {
    // 't' is named and thus is an l-value reference here.

    // Pass 't' as lvalue reference.
    some_other_func(t);
    // Pass 't' as rvalue reference (forwards rvalueness).
    some_other_func(std::forward<my_type>(t));
    // 'std::move' should be used instead as we know 't' is always an rvalue.
    // e.g. some_other_func(std::move(t));
}
```

Also you should never use `std::forward` or `std::move` on an object that you afterwards need to access some state from. Objects that are moved from are put in an *unspecified* but valid state, which basically means that you cant do anything with them except destroy or reassign a state to them.

### Arguments passed by reference to `std::bind`?

The function `std::bind` will always copy or move its arguments. I could not find an appropriate citation from the standard but [en.cppreference.com says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> *"The arguments to bind are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in std::ref or std::cref."*

This means that if you pass the argument(s) as an l-value reference then it is *copy constructed*, and if you pass it as an r-value reference then it is *move constructed*. In either way the argument(s) will *never* be passed as references.

To circumvent this you can e.g. use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) as a copyable reference wrapper that will internally keep a reference to the variable at the call site.

```
auto func = std::bind(&Foo::test, std::ref(f));
```

Or you could simply pass a pointer to `f` as you suggest.

```
auto func = std::bind(&Foo::test, &f);
```

What happens then is that `std::bind` will take an r-value reference to the temporary pointer returned from calling the address-of operator on `f`. This pointer will be *copied* (as pointers can't be moved) into the bound wrapper object returned from `std::bind`. Even though the pointer itself is copied, it will still point to the object at the call site and you will achieve the reference semantics you wanted.

Alternatively use a **lambda** that captures `f` by reference and calls the function `Foo::test`. This is IMHO the recommended approach as lambdas are more versatile and powerful than `std::bind` expressions in the general case.

```
Foo f;
f.i = 100;
auto func = [&f] { f.test(); };
f.i = 1000;
func(); // 1000
```

**Note:** for a good explanation of when to use `std::forward` see [this excellent video by Scott Meyers](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11).

Comment: Nice answer. +1 especially for the video link!

Answer (score 6):

Arguments taken by `std::bind` are actually [Universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), which can bind to both lvalues and rvalues. You cannot just pass value to `std::bind`, since that will copy it.

To pass the reference to the `std::bind` you can use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
auto func = std::bind(&Foo::test, std::ref(f));
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CS9AeU)