# Binding to a variadic member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, crtp

So here is the situation: I have two classes with static inheritance through CRTP. The base class has a run method that calls the derived method with a variadic template so that the arguments are flexible. Now the derived class contains a function object. The derived class has the implementation that is called by the base class. It may seem unnecessary but in the full version of this code more commands than just the contained function are run. Next there is a method that converts the function to a bool(void) function by binding all the variadic arguments, and instance to the the method `CrtpBase::Run`. This is where I am having an issue. I have tried two different approached, the version using a lambda is commented out. Neither method works. My goal is to have `VoidFunction` bind all the parameters so that I can execute the function at my leisure without the arguments. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template <typename D>
struct CrtpBase {
  template <typename ... Args>
  bool Run(Args&& ... args) const {
    return static_cast<D&>(*this).Impl(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
  }
};

template <typename ... Args>
struct CrtpDerived : public CrtpBase<CrtpDerived<Args ...>> {
  CrtpDerived(std::function<bool(Args ...)> function) : runable(std::move(function)) {}

  bool Impl(Args&& ... args) const {
    return this->runable(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
  }

  std::function<bool(Args ...)> runable;
};

template <typename D, typename ... Args>
std::function<bool()> VoidFunction(CrtpBase<D> base, Args&& ... args) {
//  return [&base, &args ...]()->bool{return CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>(base);};
  return std::bind(CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>, base, std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::function<bool(int&)> fn = [](int& a)->bool{a /= 2; return (a % 2) == 1;};
  CrtpDerived<int&> derived(fn);
  int x = 7;
  auto voided = VoidFunction(derived, x);
  bool out = voided();
  if ((x == 3) and (out == true)) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } else {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Edits:

1. Fixed typo in final test `(out == false)` became `(out == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from the compiler's point of view `CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>` is a nonsensical/incomplete combination of tokens. There's no such expression syntax in C++. This looks like an attempt to form a pointer-to-member, but that requires an explicit application of `&` operator

```
return std::bind(&CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>, base, std::forward<Args> (args) ...);
```

Secondly, this cast

```
static_cast<D&>(*this)
```

will attempt to cast away constness. This is not allowed in `static_cast`.

Thirdly, your

```
std::bind(&CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>, base, std::forward<Args> (args) ...);
```

<strike>binds the implied `this` parameter to a function parameter `base`. This will not work, since the `base` will be destroyed as soon as `VoidFunction` exits (or as soon as the calling expression ends)</strike>. As @aschepler correctly noted in the comments passing `base` in as `CrtpBase<D>` value sliced the original `CrtpDerived<int&>` object. Pass it in by reference and then use `&base` as argument for `std::bind`.

Fourthly, `std::bind` [will not bind "by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187192/how-to-bind-function-to-an-object-by-reference), and `std::forward` will not help you with this. This means that `a` inside your lambda `fn` will not be bound to `x`. Use `std::ref` to work around that limitation.

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template <typename D>
struct CrtpBase {
  template <typename ... Args>
  bool Run(Args&& ... args) const {
    return static_cast<const D&>(*this).Impl(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
  }
};

template <typename ... Args>
struct CrtpDerived : public CrtpBase<CrtpDerived<Args ...>> {
  CrtpDerived(std::function<bool(Args ...)> function) : runable(std::move(function)) {}

  bool Impl(Args&& ... args) const {
    return this->runable(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
  }

  std::function<bool(Args ...)> runable;
};

template <typename D, typename ... Args>
std::function<bool()> VoidFunction(CrtpBase<D> &base, Args&& ... args) {
  return std::bind(&CrtpBase<D>::template Run<Args ...>, &base, std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::function<bool(int&)> fn = [](int& a)->bool { a /= 2; return (a % 2) == 1; };
  CrtpDerived<int&> derived(fn);
  int x = 7;
  auto voided = VoidFunction(derived, std::ref(x));
  bool out = voided();
  if ((x == 3) && (out == false)) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } else {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

One last thing: I don't understand why you expect your `out` to be `false` in the end.

Comment: So, how then should I fix this? I can static cast to a `const D&`. That makes sense. It compiles. But when it runs it throws an instance of std::bad_function_call so there is still a problem somewhere.

Comment: I am guessing that the std::bad_function_call that I'm getting is because of base getting destroyed. Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: @esdanol: Yes, that is the reason. See corrected code above. It runs as expected, except that `out` is `true` in the end (as it should be).

Comment: Ah yes, that is a typo on my part. I will edit the code about and make a note of it in case somebody else looks at this post. Thank you very much!

Comment: You mentioned `base` being destroyed, and corrected it to be a reference in the fixed code, but I would also point out the object slicing that happened with the non-reference base class variable.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, you are right. And my original explanation is incorrect. `std::bind` would store an internal copy of `base` preventing it from being destroyed prematurely. It is actually the slicing that causes the problems here.

Comment: What do you mean by slicing?

Comment: @esdanol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing. In your original code the first parameter of `VoidFunction` has type `CrtpBase<D>`. And you are passing `CrtpDerived<int&> derived` as an argument, . What will happen is that a copy of `CrtpBase<D>` subobject of `derived` will get passed, not the whole `derived` object (this is "slicing"). Later, trying to cast that `base` to `CrtpDerived<int&>` will simply lead to undefined behavior since that `base` is no longer a part of any `CrtpDerived<int&>`.